# What does (function($) {...})(jQuery); do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Someone can explain me what does this code do?

```
(function($) {
    $.cookie = function(key, value, options) {
         // Body of the function here
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Wasn't is simpler just declaring in that way?

```
function cookie(key, value, options) {
     // Body of the function here
}
```

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

Answer (score 8):

This is called a closure to avoid conflicts with other libraries which are using `$`. This way you can ensure to use `$` in that function with passing `jQuery` as a param.

```
(function ($) {
   $(function () {
    .......
   });
})(jQuery); //<----passing jquery to avoid any conflict with other libraries.
```

like *Mootools*, *prototype* etc libraries also uses `$` and this closure is used to avoid any conflict.

Comment: That's one closure too much. Better use `jQuery(function($){…});`

Comment: @Bergi absolutely much shorter way.

Answer (score 5):

You're creating an anonymous function that accepts `$`, and you're immediately invoking it, passing `jQuery`. That creates a closure where `$` is `jQuery`. That is, provided that you know that `jQuery` will be a jQuery instance at the time of execution, you know also that `$` will be a jQuery instance instance in that closure. It's a safeguard against competing frameworks that might also define `$`.